# How to simplify multiple ifs statements with lambda

Tags: java, code-cleanup

How can I simplify this example code to be more elegant, for example in functional style if it possible.

```
  private static String resolveTypes(String messageType, String accountType) {
    String result = "";
    if(messageType.equals("PDF") && accountType.equals("NEXT")){
      result = "2015";
    }
    if(messageType.equals("CSV") && accountType.equals("NEXT")){
      result = "2016";
    }
    if(messageType.equals("CSV") && accountType.equals("BEFORE")){
      result = "2017";
    }
    if(messageType.equals("PDF") && accountType.equals("BEFORE")){
      result = "2018";
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How would lambdas help at all?

```
@Value
public static class MessageAccountKey {
   // this class needs a better name;
   // you'd know better what it represents
   String messageType, accountType;
}

private static final Map<MessageAccountKey, Integer> MAP = Map.of(
    new MessageAccountKey("PDF", "NEXT"), 2015,
    new MessageAccountKey("CSV", "NEXT"), 2016,
    new MessageAccountKey("CSV", "BEFORE"), 2017,
    new MessageAccountKey("PDF", "BEFORE"), 2018);

private static int resolveType(String messageType, String accountType) {
 // consider changing to a single arg of type Key.
  return MAP.getOrDefault(new MessageAccountKey(messageType, accountType), 0);
}
```

The 'key' class needs functional equals and hashCode impls, here done with [lombok's `@Value`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Value).

The MAP can also be built up from an input text file (use `getResourceAsStream` and a static initializer if you prefer.

Comment: Any particular reason the return type was changed from `String` to `int`?

Comment: Answer is not useful since it won't compile. Perhaps explaining what `@Value` is would make it useful.

Comment: @Andreas it's SO; the point is to answer questions, not to be 'do my programming work for me'. Therefore the point of an answer is to show the principle, not to be copy-pastable without so much as a glance at the code.

Comment: But you're not showing the very relevant parts of the "principle" that'll actually make it work, e.g. the fact that class `MessageAccountKey` **must** implement `equals()` and `hashCode()`. Without that VERY important detail, the answer is useless, aka *not useful!*.

Comment: Added a clarification.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a limited number of values a map could also be an alternative:

```
private static String resolveTypes(String messageType, String accountType) {
    Map<String,Map<String,String>> map = Map.of( 
            "PDF",Map.of("NEXT", "2015", "BEFORE","2016"),
            "CSV",Map.of("NEXT", "2017", "BEFORE","2018"));
    return map.getOrDefault(messageType, new HashMap<>()).getOrDefault(accountType, "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could combine the strings, with a separator, then use a `switch` statement:

```java
private static String resolveTypes(String messageType, String accountType) {
    switch (messageType + ':' + accountType) {
        case "PDF:NEXT": return "2015";
        case "CSV:NEXT": return "2016";
        case "CSV:BEFORE": return "2017";
        case "PDF:BEFORE": return "2018";
        default: return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: but @rzwitserloot answer is better

Comment: @merc-angel Then you should accept that answer. You can still have both up-voted.